# Unhandled exception at 0x6c70f2ca in xxx.exe 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdf1 how to debug this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

i have c application that im compiling in visual studio 2010
im getting this error in one of my functions 
generically how can i debug this kind of exception ?
the function is from dll , other functions working but not this one .

Comment: You've produced nowhere near enough code. It's also worth noting that this exception is a Windows Structured Exception, not a C++ exception.

Comment: So, what happens when you run your application under the debugger?

Answer (score 3):

The debug memory allocator fills newly-allocated memory with 0xcdcdcdcd. It looks like you've allocated some memory, only set the low byte to 0xf1 (241), and tried to derefence a four-byte pointer at that location. Without seeing code, that's as much as I can discern.

Comment: He's not 'set the low byte to 0xf1' he's got a structure pointer that is not initialised (thus 0xcdcdcdcd), and then he is accessing the member at 0x24 in the structure.

Answer (score 1):

The error most likely happens when trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer. So:

1. Recompile with warning level on
   maximum (4). Review the warnings.
   You'll find listed the local
   variables that are declared without
   initialization (including pointers).
2. Check the parameters you pass to the function (especially the pointer/reference parameters). Check their initialization.